# Experiencing delay in displaying wpf window

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window which shows up on a button click. There is a delay of some seconds to display the window. I have commented out the part where it takes value from the database and the part where it displays a popup on window load. Window contains certain telerik controls only. Can anyone please tell me what are the possibilites of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the window hanging for a couple of seconds or is it invisible and needs a couple of seconds until it becomes visible? Maybe you have code being executed in some initialization method of the window.

Comment: If all you have left are controls then you need to start looking at the controls.  You can comment out the XAML.  Comment out all you controls and see if you get response time.  If so add back controls one a time to find the offender(s).

Comment: it needs couple of seconds to become visible

Comment: If it still takes a couple seconds with all the control commented out then need to keep digging.  Are you opening any database connections?  Look in app you might be running something there you are not aware of.

Comment: Please post your code for the button event that displays the window.

Comment: MyWindow w1 = new MyWindow ();
            Window xyz = (Window)w1;
            Utils.setWindowSettings(ref xyz);

           
            w1.Drive = drive;

            Hide();
            w1.Show();

Comment: well, i have only commented out the code in constructor and window load function

Answer (score 0):

Check the DataContext and if you have any big loop, you could use
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/
to know where your application is hanging.